# Leasing a server from 1and1; do I need to download remote desktop, or something to access the server?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, hosting

I am completely new to this; in the past, I could make a simple site in Visual Studio and use ws_ftp to upload files to the server. But now, we're leasing our own server from 1and1, and here's what they said:

"**you actually lease a server from us. You will need to either administer the server directly through Remote Desktop or take advantage of your Parallels Small Business Panel. Your operating system is Windows Web Server 2008. I do not know if the server comes preinstalled with asp.net 4.0, but you do have full administrator access to your server and can install any necessary software.**"

My goal is to make a small website in Visual Studio / vb / asp.net 4.0.

Could anybody offer any basic simple steps that I'll need to do now that I have my own server? I'm confused about what I need to download in order to manipulate the server (remote desktop, parallels small business panel, etc.).

So any guidance anybody could offer me, like some simple, basic steps I need to take, or the difference between now and when I used to just have a website hosted on one of theier servers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How about calling their support desk?  Posting same question to here and Serverfault is usually frowned upon http://serverfault.com/questions/381225/i-am-now-leasing-a-win-2008-server-what-steps-should-i-take-remote-desktop-et

Comment: Hi Dave.  I originally posted it on serverfault, and they redirected me to this website, as you see in the link you provided.  So I was just doing what they told me to do.  The 1and1 support desk is terrible, and they're very slow to respond.  But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote Desktop client software is available on all Windows machines and allows you to log in to a remote server and act as if you were physically sitting in front of the machine. From the tone of the 1and1 answer I suspect it is your responsibility to maintain the server, including installing and configuring the necessary software to get your web server up and running to your liking.

1. Start Remote Desktop on your machine
2. Enter the DNS-name or IP-address of your server
3. Enter your username and password for accessing the server
4. Do whatever you like with your server

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, Erik .... I do appreciate it.  I think I have an idea now .... that it's really not too much different than using your own deskop/laptop once you set up the remote desktop.  Thanks again!